# STL <set> search

Tags: c++, stl

I want to store unique strings and detect duplicates.
I thought I will use STL set container for this, but my string is char*
so I did `set<char *>` but when I want to search for an item how would I do it? Since it is comparing pointer values and not values.

Comment: "but my string is char*". That's your problem right here. Why?

Comment: i am not allowed using <string>

Comment: Why would anyone allow `std::set` but forbid `std::string`? How does that make sense?

Comment: well, ask my teacher that :)

Comment: @lllook: In that case, write your own wrapper class for char* to mimic a basic version of `std::string`

Comment: @AndyG Eh, too much work for a throw away assignment. One has better things to do in school / university I think.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Well, it can be quite enlightening having to write a string class by yourself. The problem is that a student may become overly proud of his or her work when it's done and works, and take too long to realise that `std::string` is still superior to the cool home-made solution in any possible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) can be used whenever you can provide a sensible definition of "one element is less than the other". To make this feature as flexible as possible, it has a template argument which defaults to `std::less<T>` and which denotes the less-than comparison function to be used.

In other words, **`std::set<char*>` is short for `std::set<char*, std::less<char*>>`** <sup>[*]</sup>.

`std::less<T>` is a somewhat "magic" functor, because it allows one to safely compare pointers and get defined results for the comparison (which is, surprisingly, not the case if you compare pointers directly via `<`).

This does not help you here, though. You don't want to compare pointers at all, you want to dereference the pointers and inspect the values they are pointing to.

In order to do so, just instantiate the `std::set` template with a comparison argument that does exactly that. The pointer-based [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) C function helps you to perform the actual comparison. Here is an example:

```
struct CStringPointerComparison
{
    bool operator()(char const* lhs, char const* rhs) const
    {
        return std::strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
};

std::set<char*, CStringPointerComparison> my_set;
```

---

<sup>[*] Which is itself short for `std::set<char*, std::less<char*>, std::allocator<char*>>`, but the allocator is not important here.</sup>

Comment: Can that be `CStringPointerComparison` or something? Your name is a touch overly-generic.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Renamed it :)

Comment: thanks I didnt know about this "hidden" argument where you can specify comparator, does every STL container have this ?

Comment: @lllook: All container class templates in the C++ standard library have at least one "hidden" template argument for the allocation function, yes. Some, like `std::set`, have even more arguments. Have a look at the documentation at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: @lllook: Actually, that's not true. `std::array` is the exception to the rule :)

Answer (score 2):

First choice (by a wide margin) is to store `std::string`s instead.

In theory, the second choice is to supply a comparison object (or function) when you construct your set. At least in my opinion, however, this is generally more of a pain than it's worth. If you really want to do it, code looks something like this:

```
auto cmp = [](char const *a, char const *b) { return strcmp(a, b) < 0; };

std::set<char *, decltype(cmp)> more(cmp);

more.insert("Third");
more.insert("First");
more.insert("Second");
```

That leaves what I consider a more practical<sup>1</sup> choice of defining your own little string class that supports the operations you really need, something on this general order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class my_str {
    char const *data;
public:
    my_str(char const *data) : data(data) {}

    bool operator<(my_str const &other) const {
        return strcmp(data, other.data) < 0;
    }

    operator char const *() const { return data; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, my_str const &m) {
        return os << m.data;
    }
};
```

Note: this only stores the pointer that you passed to it when you constructed it. It doesn't try to store a copy of the data (like `std::string` does) so it's up to you to ensure that every string you pass to it remains valid for the lifetime of the object. That's trivial with string literals, but generally untenable for almost anything else (which, of course, is a large part of why `std::string` works the way it does).

To use this, you'd do something like this:

```
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<my_str> strings{"xyz", "abc"};

    for (auto const &s : strings)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

But do heed the warning above: this string class is much too bare-bones to be of much real use. Worse, if you use it incorrectly (especially in a small test) there's a pretty fair chance that problems with your usage won't be visible immediately.

---

<sup>1. It's possible, however, that my beliefs about this are affected by having written C++98/03 for a lot longer than I've written more modern C++.</sup>

Comment: this looks like what I am searching for, but how do i use it now? I know very little about lambda functions. if i now use x.insert(a) x.insert(b) it will use this lambdra function to sort it ?

Comment: This won't compile because `std::set<char*>` misses the template argument  to replace `std::less<char*>`.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `==-1`, which would sort in increasing order instead of decreasing, thus matching the default
?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think the standard only guarantees a negative result and not `-1`, so it should be `< 0`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `std::set<std::string>`.  A `std::set<char *>` is a set of *pointers*.

To find a target object, you will need to dereference a *pointer*.  So, I recommend (*if you keep it as a set of pointers*):

1. Iterating through the set:
2. In each iteration, use `strcmp`  to compare the `set` item with your
   target C-Style string.

If you use an iterator, you will need to dereference the iterator before passing it to the `strcmp` function.

Note:  If you used `std::set<std::string>` you could using the `find` algorithm, or a method in set.  No dereferencing required.

Simplify your life, use `std::string`.

Comment: i am not allowed to use string otherwise i would, I now use linear search, i wanted to use set to be able to search in Log time

Comment: @lllook That you can do by binary searching through a sorted `std::vector` btw. Depending on your usecase, it might be faster.

Comment: 1) Unless you have a HUGE data set or timing is critical, a linear search will have roughly the same time as a log based search (for small data sets).  2) Your time is wasted by having to dereference pointers.

Comment: There are more efficient data structures for handling string types, such as a *trie*.  Also, search the internet for "optimal string search algorithm".